# Test if a link does not exist on the page in Rspec/Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have 2 scenarios in capybara. The first one checks if a link is present on the page and the second one checks if it is absent.

I was able to get the first test passing by using the following method:

```
expect(page).to have_link('act_id')
```

I tried using the following method for the second test.

```
expect(page).to not_have_link('act_id')
```

but I am getting following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `not_have_link'
```

How can I test if a link does not exist on the page ??

**Ruby version: 2.2**

**Rails version:  4.2**

Comment: try something like this with expath
(page).not_to have_xpath('a')

expect(page).to have_no_xpath('a')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
expect(page).to have_no_link('act_id')
```

Comment: You can also do `expect(page).not_to have_link('act_id')`

Comment: There is some intricacies to be aware of between these two ways of asserting. `have_no_link` assumes the link to not be there and passes right away when it's not there, while `have_link` assumes that the link should be there and takes longer to return its result because it is waiting for the link to be found.

Comment: Actually those intricacies don't exist when using the RSpec matchers (which this example is). In that case `.not_to have_link` and `.to have_no_link` are functionally equivalent because of the way RSpec processes not_to/to_not.  The intricacies you mention do exist if you are using boolean checks (has_link?, has_no_link?, etc) or the assert_xxx methods provided by Capybara -

Comment: That is true, the differences in behavior are caused by Capybara.

Comment: It's not "caused by capybara" - the differences don't exist when using the RSpec matchers Capybara provides - they do exist when using the non rspec matchers/assertions Capybara provides.

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(page).not_to have_link('act_id')
```

For RSpec this has the same effect as the excepted answer `expect(page).to have_no_link('act_id')`. While this is true for RSpec in some other frameworks the test for "link missing" [waits before moving on](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends) but the test for "link found" does not wait.

(Answer taken from a comment from Thomas Walpole - a member of teamcapybara)